# From IoT Hub to SQL Database

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-iot-hub

I sent data to IoT Hub using Mosquitto:

```
 mosquitto_pub  <..> -m "mensaje" <..>
```

I have tested that this message arrive to IoT Hub with "device explorer twin" and also with the CLI

But after that, when I create a stream analytics jobs, the input fail

[input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gliRG.jpg)

I have tried all kind of formart: CSV, JSON, AVRO and also all king of string format with -m "mensaje" like: {"mensaje":"adios"}

There is no way to do this from the CMD with the command mosquitto_pub?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not send the message in JSON/CSV/AVRO format from Mosquitto to Azure so I had to change to other Mosquitto broker and that work without problem